# Random Question Mark Icons In WordPress Text

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, typekit

I am re-designing a WordPress site, and I imported all of the many thousand articles and noticed all of these little icons showing up randomly in the text. Sometimes it takes up 1 character, sometimes a whole sentence.

[image]
[image]

They also show up in the source the same way: �����

Tried different themes, as well as TypeKit/Google Fonts and am getting the same result.

Any ideas? `langAttribute` issue?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to display non-utf-8 text as utf-8. Find out the encoding and use that to display the text instead of utf-8.

Comment: I copied the same one that was on the old site. It was <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Use a hex editor to look at one or more of the errant characters in the source.  If that doesn't make the answer luminously obvious, please edit your question to reflect what you found.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man. Rookie move.

Issue was my wp-config file.

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Once I added that I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that are still wondering how to do that.

I have tried all the above and as nothing of that worked for me, I have found the following solution:

As my sql file was with latin1 encoding, I added the following lines to my wp-config.php file:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'latin1');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'latin1_swedish_ci');
```

AFTER that I imported the database and the issue was resolved.

So, just change the DB define values in your wp-config file to the ones that your database requires and then import the database. ^^